# Joomla 3.2 fresh install many unfound paths

Tags: php, html, joomla, web

I have just made a fresh install of Joomla 3.2, which is the latest version at this time.  It is installed here:

[frobtek.robotoholic.com](http://frobtek.robotoholic.com)

I have successfully installed and used Joomla many times, and this installation was very easy and competed successfully.  The problem which I am having trouble troubleshooting is, when you click on "create an account" button, I get the 404 error.  When I click "forgot your username" or "forgot your password" i get the same thing.

I have just barely installed this and I could just as easily delete it and try again, which I already did and I tried 3.1.5 instead.  It is strange that I get the same problem with the links.  I was just wondering if this pops out at anyone as an obvious problem?  What am I overlooking here?

I did an installation about a month ago of 3.1.5 which works perfectly, so I am not sure what I did wrong here.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

I should add that the back-end administration interface is working without any problems at all.  I am able to make changes and manage the site.

Comment: If you turn SEF URL's off in the Global Configuration, do you still have the same issue?

Comment: That has fixed the problem... Thanks a lot!  However I would love to have the SEF URLs enabled.  DO you have any idea what I could do to fix it?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the way joomla is using the path.  I installed this site in a folder inside my html folder, called frobtek.  The subdomain frobtek.robotoholic.com points directly to that folder.  On that error page I also get some browser errors.  see here: http://frobtek.robotoholic.com/index.php/component/users/?view=registration.  It can't find the image at: `http://frobtek.robotoholic.com/frobtek/images/FTlogotypeJPG.jpg` because the correct path should be: `http://frobtek.robotoholic.com/images/FTlogotypeJPG.jpg`.  It should not be adding the `/frobtek` to the path.

Answer (score 0):

In the Global Configuration, try using the following settings:

- **Search Engine Friendly URLs** - *Yes*
- **Use URL rewriting** - *No*
- **Adds Suffix to URL** - *No*
- **Unicode Aliases** - *No*

Once done, if this doesn't resolve the issue, try renaming the htaccess file from:

`htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess`

Hope this helps

Comment: yes i tried this.  Doesn't seem to work.  It is strange, a previously installed site works correctly "out-of-the-box" on the same host, but another subdirectory.  It worked without any need for modification...